# Backing up Google Photos collection to an external microSDXC card (with a exFAT filesystem)

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, android, micro-sd-card, google-photos

SWIM has a *Motorola moto e5 play* with *Android 8* as the OS.  This individual wants to backup their entire photo (& video) collection stored on Google Photos, and move it entirely onto a 128GB microSDXC Card they can insert into their smartphone [Note: the microSDXC Card is currently formatted with an **exFat** filesystem].

ATM, the microSDXC card disc/volume is visible in Windows 10 (via *Disc Management & My PC*) with an SD-Card Adaptor.  The *moto e5 play* itself is plugged in the Windows 10 machine with a microUSB cable, while the microSD card slot remains empty, **yet no drive/disc/volume is visible, when the phone should have at least 16gb of native, at capacity, memory**.

**Q:  What is the most efficient way to pull this off?**

1. Must the microSDXC Card be reformatted?  If a laptop running Windows 10 is being used as an intermediary, must the Card be entirely reformatted to a NSFT filesystem?
2. How can this individual take/save photos, going forward, directly to the microSDXC card when it's inserted back into the phone's microSD card slot?

Comment: IMO this is 10 times easier to access Google Photos from Chrome on a PC or Mac and download and backup from there. BTW, the way I read you question, you're asking three questions, each should be in it's own topic.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, first you need to go and install a Motorola driver and/or a software package that includes a driver.

Then you are likely need to enable developer USB mode under settings on the phone.

This can be a bit annoying as usually you have to tap something like 15-30 times on something in settings.  Maybe "about phone", but it could be different.

After that a hidden menu/menu options that should allow you to enable developer mode for the USB port.

Hopefully that should allow you access to the internal phone/sd card.

Android 8 is very very very old, and you may or may not experience additional difficulties.